# How to work with Resouce.txt in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, resources

what i tried is created a new `Resource.txt` file at desktop and runned a command in Visual Studio Command prompt `resgen Resource.txt @Resource.rsp`?

> Error::RG0000:Specified Responce File does not exist//Responce.rsp.

Why I am getting this?

**Updated**
.net gives us .resx format to create resource. Then how it would be possible to create .txt resources????

Updated
.net gives us .resx format to create resource. Then how it would be possible to create .txt resources in >net Framework????

Comment: The error message and the posted command prompt do not agree with each other. Are you sure you posted the correct ones?

Comment: Does it have to be .txt? If you consider XML, you could use Linq to XML to create a resource document. Have a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387089.aspx).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference b/w Resource.txt and Resource.resx in ASP.Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937562/what-is-the-difference-b-w-resource-txt-and-resource-resx-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

`resgen Resource.txt @Resource.rsp` is not a valid command parameter. Have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccec7sz1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) article.

```
resgen Resource.txt
```

EDIT:

You may specify .resx exension to resource file.

```
resgen Resource.txt Resource.resx
```

Use WebSite Menu + Add Existing Item to add resource (Resource.resx) file into your web-project or just copy+paste into `App_GlobalResources` (website project) folder.

Comment: When i used it then Error comes: which says Response file is like something @Response.rsp instead [Response.rsp]

Comment: Just create sample.txt and generate sample.resources using resgen sample.txt command line. Why adding @Response.rsp?

Comment: AVD frankly speaking i dont have any idea how to use txt Resources. Where to create sample.txt(anywhere?)

Comment: i generated a file sample.resources on desktop itself. Now how can i use that resource in my application(asp.net)

Comment: .net gives us .resx format to create resource. Then how it would be possible to create .txt resources????This is what i am asking?